# I'm getting a "Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/dashboard/dashboard.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable

Tags: html, express, browser, ejs

My code works when I use

`<script> //my js code </script>`

But I'm trying to put my JavaScript code outside my ejs(HTML) file,

- I create new js file I put my code inside
- I import to my ejs file

  ```
  <script src="../js/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
  ```

and my browser show me this error :

`GET http://localhost:3000/js/dashboard/dashboard.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

`dashboard:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/dashboard/dashboard.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

When I go in postman and do http GET request to see the header (content-type): I notice this :

[image: postman GET request]

How can I change MIME content type or just simply avoid this MIME error.

[image]

and this is my arichitecure :

[image]

Trying to avoid MIME error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess you are serving your app from the `/public` directory. Something in your `app.js` along the lines of:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
```

or

```js
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If so, that means any JavaScript you want your **front-end** to use such as DOM manipulation and adding event listeners etc needs to be located in the same `/public` directory. From looking at your file layout it would appear `dashboard.js` is within it's own `/js` directory. That means it's only available to Node.js on the **back-end**.

As a simple solution, just create a new folder: `/public/js` and put the `dashboard.js` in there.

For clarity, move your file to here:

`/public/js/dashboard.js`

Change your `<script>` tag to:

```html
<script src="/js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

The `MIME type ('text/html')` is a red herring because if you actually look at the response, there is likely some error message there... presented in HTML.